# Iterate over data frame by elements of a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, iteration, purrr

I am trying to merge two data frames based on a subset on common IDs. Let me demonstrate:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

df = list(id = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,1,1),
       group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C"),
       val = c(round(rnorm(10,6,6),0))
       ) %>% 
        tbl_df()

df_na = list(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5),
       group = c(rep(NA,10)),
       val = c(rep(NA,10))
       ) %>% 
        tbl_df()
```

`df` contains data and `id`s, while `df_na` only contains `id`s and `NA`s. I would like to create a combined data frame that contains all the information of `df` and add the `NA`s by `group` and `id`, i.e. for each `group` in `df` find which `id`s are present in both `df` and `df_na` and merge.

If I was doing this manually, i.e. group for group, I would use something like this:

```
A_dist = df %>% filter(group=="A") %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  pull() 

df_A_comb = df_na %>% 
  filter(id %in% A_dist) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(df, group=="A"))

# A tibble: 11 x 3
      id group   val
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 NA       NA
 2     1 NA       NA
 3     1 NA       NA
 4     2 NA       NA
 5     3 NA       NA
 6     3 NA       NA
 7     4 NA       NA
 8     1 A        14
 9     2 A         3
10     3 A         8
11     4 A        10
```

But obvioulsy, I would rather automate this. As an emerging fan of the `tidyverse`, I'm trying to get my head around `purrr::map`. I can create a vector of `id`s for each `group`.

```
df_dist = df %>% 
        split(.$group) %>% 
        map(distinct, id) %>% 
        map("id")

> df_dist
$A
[1] 1 2 3 4

$B
[1] 1 2

$C
[1] 1
```

But translating my `dplyr` approach is more complicated and produces an error message earlier on.

```
###this approach doesn't work...
df_comb = df_na %>% 
        map(filter, id %in% df_dist)# %>% 
        ...
```

`Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Any help will be much appreaciated!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do by calling `filter` inside of `bind_rows`; just filter inside a `map` the same as you did in the line above. `bind_rows` can take a list, so whatever resulting list of data frames you get, just pass it to `bind_rows`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I have made some edits to my question. I run into an error early on and I don't understand how to integrate iterating over each `group` in `df` into my present approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tidyverse is great, but sometimes you can overlook the power of simple indexing and the really useful base R tools of the `apply` family. This single `lapply` function will give you a list containing all the data frames you want in the specified format:

```r
lapply(unique(df$group), function(x){
  rbind(df_na[df_na$id %in% df$id[df$group == x],], df[df$group == x,])})
```

Result:

```r
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>       id group   val
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     1 <NA>     NA
#>  2     1 <NA>     NA
#>  3     1 <NA>     NA
#>  4     2 <NA>     NA
#>  5     3 <NA>     NA
#>  6     3 <NA>     NA
#>  7     4 <NA>     NA
#>  8     1 A        14
#>  9     2 A         3
#> 10     3 A         8
#> 11     4 A        10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>      id group   val
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 <NA>     NA
#> 2     1 <NA>     NA
#> 3     1 <NA>     NA
#> 4     2 <NA>     NA
#> 5     1 B         8
#> 6     2 B         5
#> 7     2 B        15
#> 8     2 B         5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id group   val
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 <NA>     NA
#> 2     1 <NA>     NA
#> 3     1 <NA>     NA
#> 4     1 C        18
#> 5     1 C         6
```

If you want to join them into a single data frame, store the result (say as `x`) and do this:

```
do.call(rbind, x)
```